# URL scheme to launch blackberry messenger in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, url-scheme, bb-messenger

If i need to check whether Facebook is installed on my iOS device, i can check it by :

`if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]])`

Is there any url scheme for bbm ?

I have tried for bbm://, but didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the url scheme, its bbmc:// , You can detect whether bbm is installed on your iOS device by

`if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"bbmc://"]])`

Blackberry should provide it on its site like instagram did [like this.](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. If you want to know for certain, you can open the ipa for it (it's a zip file), and find the plist. Within the plist, you can check if it registers any schemes.

Comment: Thanks @fernando, I got plist of bbm from iTunes folder but haven't got url scheme. Even for others like Facebook, its not there in facebook's plist.

Comment: They need to be. It's the only way to register them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found three URL schemes for the app:

- `bbmi://`
- `pin://`
- `bbmc://`

it is unknown what they are really doing after the application opens.